# How can I find an unauthorized/unknown proxy on my home network?

Tags: network, web-browser, vpn, proxy, ip

I recently started receiving an error while trying to stream netflix that I'm using a proxy. Exactly this error code here: https://help.netflix.com/en/node/277?ba=GSButtonClick&q=

My problem is that I'm not using a proxy (or an 'unblocker')! I'm just connecting through my ISP (Comcast).

How can I pinpoint the root of the problem, whatever proxy my internet is going through?

The error occurs both on my laptop, xbox (in netflix application) and iPad (in netflix app). The rest of the internet works perfectly fine and fast.

Edit: Just found out that my roommate can stream Netflix just fine with his account on the same home wifi network. I'm officially completely confused.

Comment: Technically you can use a `traceroute` to diagnose the path between your computer and Netflix. But if you didn't install a proxy yourself and are not using a VPN service, it's unlikely to be the problem (especially since it's on all your devices). Netflix probably mislabeled your IP address. I'd contact them to see if they can clarify the situation.

Comment: 'traceroute' was my first thought also, but I didn't notice anything I considered to be suspicious, it just went right into comcast routers. I gave my ASN and IP to Netflix via email, hopefully they'll get back to me soon.

Comment: `traceroute` can not detect if there's a transparent proxy somewhere. You will need to use a tool to detect the request headers you are sending. http://www.reliply.org/tools/requestheaders.php is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with what Drewbenn commented.

It appears that your account was opened in a significantly different geographical location.  Netflix recently made changes to what type of traffic they will permit to stream.  Without knowing more about where you opened your account and where you now reside it's difficult to pin that down as the problem.  See below:

http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/netflix-blocking-vpns-everything-you-need-know-about-fight-stop-you-seeing-us-content-1538255

Aside from that, if your roommate was connecting over the exact same network and you're both receiving IP settings from the same DHCP server and neither of you have custom Proxy settings on your browsers or any other application performing proxy or redirecting then it comes down to a matter of your account.  A good test would be to have your friend access his account on your machine and vice versa.

Happy Steaming.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether your current IP is on a proxy list. Since your IP address is assigned dynamically, it could be that the former owner got himself onto a proxy list - these lists get generically blocked by many pages.

It is, however, easier, just to get a new IP and try again.

Comment: Are there any proxy lists that you would recommend looking on? or will any google result for "proxy list" be adequate and sufficient? 
Also, while I don't have a static IP from my ISP, my ip has been constant over the last ~9 months over many modem and router reboots. Any special tips on how to get a new IP?

Comment: Edited my post. You should get a new IP first to check whether your IP is the cause.

Comment: Your IP has been static for 9 months? Then you have a cable connection, you need to unplug your modem for some hours OR get a new mac address since cable IPs are related to mac addresses.

Answer (score -4):

How paranoid are you and how much money do you have to spend?  If you have money to spend then I would go to a local big box store and buy a cheap laptop off the shelf.  Take it to a local library, unbox it there, wipe  it clean,  download a decent Linux security distro livecd and install it on the laptop. SecurityOnion isn't bad.

One thing to look for is arp table poisoning of your default gateway's IP address.

For bonus points buy a laptop with dongles or some other ability to have two Ethernet cables  installed so that you can have the laptop act as a network sniffer. If you insert the laptop between the cable/dsl modem and your router / switch and bridge the networks then you can sniff all the traffic in and out of your network. Unfortunately the details of how to use the tools in a distro like SecurityOnion is probably beyond the scope of this answer.  Read the docs for the tools that come with the distro to learn how to use them.

Comment: Why so much trouble? Buy 2 USB ethernet dongles, bridge them, put between the modem and router, run a live Linux distro.

Comment: In this day and age with the prevalence of UEFi You have to assume that one a machine has been rooted, there is potentially a malicious payload in the pre-boot environment.

Comment: But it's a *very* long shot to expect that someone hacked the preboot, installed a rootkit, infected your OS, installed an intercepting proxy and is messing with your NetFlix. It's way more probably that someone installed a proxy, got listed, got another IP and you got the listed IP.

Comment: The OP a) didn't ask what was more likely, they asked _how to detect_. It's not our job to dissuade him of his suspicions and b) the OP specifically mentioned that his roommate, who we can assume is on the same network, has no problem with Netflix.

Comment: Also pre boot UEFi malware is increasingly included in black market root kits.  Instead of assuming that it's not happening, it's time to start assuming it is.

Comment: I think it's funny that I've gotten so many down votes. This is the infosec stack exchange is it not? The OP question was about detecting a proxy. Netflix might have been an example, but this wasn't a question about Netflix. My answer is perfectly reasonable if someone wants to find a rogue proxy.